# Does Raspberry Pi 3.0 support HDMI 2.0 standard?

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, data-transfer, measuring

I am not able to see specific protocol version of HDMI (1.4 or 2.0) supported by RPI 3.0. Basically I want to take HDMI 2.0 output from RPI and provide it to my device.

Also can we measure the rate of output HDMI signal?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Since RPi 3 uses BCM2837 SoC, you're [out of luck](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/RPI-CM-DATASHEET-V1_0.pdf):

> BCM283x supports HDMI V1.3a.

Not sure what the "rate of output" means, but HDMI 1.3a runs at a frequency of 340 MHz and a data rate of 10.2 Gbps. No need to measure that.